# Does a thread really start after std::future::get() is called?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrent.futures

I created a for loop to define a `std::vector` of `std::future` to execute my function `vector<int> identify` and another loop to get the results by calling `std::future::get()` as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
    VecString::const_iterator first = dirList.begin() + i*share;
    VecString::const_iterator last = i == NUM_THREADS - 1 ? dirList.end() : dirList.begin() + (i + 1)*share;
    VecString job(first, last);
    futures[i] = async( launch::async, [=]() -> VecInt {
        return identify(i, job, make_tuple( bIDList, wIDList, pIDList, descriptor), testingDir, binaryMode, logFile, logFile2 );
    } );
}

int correct = 0;
int numImages = 0;
for( int i = 0; i != NUM_THREADS; ++i ) {
    VecInt ret = futures[i].get();
    correct += ret[0];
    numImages += ret[1];
}
```

The job is to process some images and I divide the work roughly equally between each thread. I also embed `std::cout` in the function to indicate which thread the results come from.

I expect that after the first thread finishes its work, others should also completes theirs and the loop will print the results out. However, after the first thread finishes, other threads still work. I think they really work, not just print the results out because there is some delay when the function processes a big image. This makes me wonder when the threads really start.

I know from the documentation that each thread starts right away after its initialization but how can you explain my observation? Thank you very much and any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: i added my code snippet for clarity.

Comment: My first thought is that your cout may come in a buffer and is not printed directly.
Try printing out a time/clock to be sure when it starts, further than that I am not familiar with threads.

Comment: Again, [mcve] implies in this case the code should be able to be compiled and ran, not the gist of it. And don't paste the entire program, slim it down to the *minimum*

Comment: `std::cout` is not thread-safe without adding your own synchronization (e.g. a `std::mutex` controlling access. Also flush on each output e.g. finishing with `<<std::endl;`.

Comment: @DanAllen: yes i did use `mutex` and `std::endl` at the end of each `std::cout`.

Comment: @DucNguyen That's good then. Your output will be a reasonable representation. But also be aware that if you do lots of output that will actually force/increase serialization. You should provide the [mcve] that others have asked for and sample output.

Comment: @DanAllen thanks very much for your feedback. as a matter of fact, yes i use 7 `std::cout`s in the `identity`. can you be more specific about the increase in serialization? and sorry for the format of the question. i will be more careful next time.

Comment: @DucNguyen It's hard to be specific without some detailed analysis. It's just important to see that you have tasks that are logically independent and run in parallel UNTIL you add a global mutex to control cout and threads they end up contending for that and you can find that the threads line up and go in series through cout and the parallelism you're designing for gets diminished. Try it with a 'starting thread x' and 'finishing thread x' message only that will tell you something about parallelism.

Comment: @DanAllen yeah i see. i will reduce the number of outputs. thank you again for all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `std::launch::async`, it's up to `std::async` to determine how to schedule your requests.  According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async):

> The template function async runs the function f asynchronously (potentially in a separate thread which may be part of a thread pool) and returns a `std::future` that will eventually hold the result of that function call.

It does guarantee that they will be threaded, however, and you can infer that the evaluation of your lambda will be scheduled to happen at the next available opportunity:

> If the *async* flag is set (i.e. `policy & std::launch::async != 0`), then async executes the callable object f on a new thread of execution (with all thread-locals initialized) as if spawned by `std::thread(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)`, except that if the function f returns a value or throws an exception, it is stored in the shared state accessible through the `std::future` that async returns to the caller.

For the purposes of your question, however, you just wanted to know when it's executed in relation to your call to `get`.  It's easy to demonstrate that `get` has nothing to do with the execution of async tasks when launched with `std::launch::async`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto timestamp = [start]( ostream & s )->ostream& {
        auto now = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(now - start);
        return s << "[" << elapsed.count() << "us] ";
    };

    vector<future<int>> futures;
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        futures.emplace_back( async(launch::async,
            [=](){
                timestamp(cout) << "Launch " << i << endl;
                return i;
            } ) );
    }

    this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(100) );

    for( auto & f : futures ) timestamp(cout) << "Get " << f.get() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output ([live example here](http://ideone.com/BEruzI)):

```
[42us] Launch 4
[85us] Launch 3
[95us] Launch 2
[103us] Launch 1
[109us] Launch 0
[100134us] Get 0
[100158us] Get 1
[100162us] Get 2
[100165us] Get 3
[100168us] Get 4
```

These operations are trivial, but if you have long-running tasks then you can expect that some or all of those tasks might still be executing when you call `std::future<T>::get()`.  In that case, your thread will be suspended until the *promise* associated with that *future* is satisfied.  Also, because the async tasks may be pooled it's possible that some will not begin evaluation until after others have completed.

If you use instead `std::launch::deferred`, then you will get lazy evaluation on the calling thread, and so the output would be something like:

```
[100175us] Launch 0
[100323us] Get 0
[100340us] Launch 1
[100352us] Get 1
[100364us] Launch 2
[100375us] Get 2
[100386us] Launch 3
[100397us] Get 3
[100408us] Launch 4
[100419us] Get 4
[100430us] Launch 5
```

Comment: You should protect `cout` accesses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It cleared my doubt now. i have another question. in the code you print the elapsed time but how can i print the time when the function is called by a thread. I used `auto t = time(nullptr); auto tm = *localtime(&t);` inside the function but im not sure if it's right.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, in the future pattern `get` usually blocks until the result is set to the future. This result can also be an exception. Thus setting a result from the other thread will unblock get. Same occurs if the exception is propagated to the future.

Here is the link to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) which describes this:

> The get method waits until the future has a valid result and (depending on which template is used) retrieves it. It effectively calls wait() in order to wait for the result.

Threads are not guaranteed to run in the order you created them or even in the order application assigned smth. for it to do.

It can happen, that you are lucky and wait on the future which bears the result for the last queued job and thus all others are done and you don't notice any blocking, but it can be vice versa as well.

**std::async**: Does not guarantee any asynchronous execution. Here is what [reference states](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async):

> The template function async runs the function f asynchronously (**potentially in a separate thread** which may be part of a thread pool) and returns a std::future that will eventually hold the result of that function call.

Further is stated:

> If the async flag is set (i.e. policy & std::launch::async != 0), then async executes the callable object f on a **new thread of execution** (with all thread-locals initialized) as if spawned by std::thread(std::forward(f), std::forward(args)...), except that if the function f returns a value or throws an exception, it is stored in the shared state accessible through the std::future that async returns to the caller.

Can you first try to run a version of `std::async` without any policy, it **should/might** reuse an internal thread-pool. If it runs faster, than the problem might be that the application does not re-use threads?

Finally, the reference to async has a note, which states when the **execution can be synchronous**:

> The implementation may extend the behavior of the first overload of std::async by enabling additional (implementation-defined) bits in the default launch policy.
>   Examples of implementation-defined launch policies are the sync policy (execute immediately, within the async call) and the task policy (similar to async, but thread-locals are not cleared)
>
> **If the std::future obtained from std::async is not moved from or bound to a reference, the destructor of the std::future will block at the end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes, essentially making code such as the following synchronous**:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); }); // temporary's dtor waits for f()
std::async(std::launch::async, []{ g(); }); // does not start until f() completes
```

Debugging multi-threaded applications is a bit hard. I'd suggest creating just one additional thread and make all job/futures run through it and see if there are some misconceptions in the execution. At this point main thread would not disturb as it just waits for results.

You can also use some logging library which is thread-safe (e.g. Boost Log) and record what's going on there and how many different threads are created by `std::async` by logging out the thread-id and if these threads are re-used at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for the references. Clearly, I missed a lot of information. Thanks for the answer again.